# How can I show an alert on a button click of a menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
 Menu{
                               Button("Profile", action: {})
                               Button("Settings", action: {})
                    Button(action: {
                               self.showingAlert = true
                           }, label: {
                               Text("Logout")
                           })
                    
                } label: {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }) {
                        Image( "icon-menu").imageScale(.large)
                            
                    }
                }.alert(isPresented:$showingAlert){
                    Alert(title: Text("Logout?"), message: Text("Are you sure you want to logout?"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {
                       
                       
                    }), secondaryButton: .cancel())
                }
```

Alert is not showing on the click of logout. Can someone help on this

I need to show an alert on the click of a menu item. But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works well for me. This is the code I used for testing, on real devices ios 16.3 and macCatalyst with macos 13.2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Button("Profile", action: {})
            Button("Settings", action: {})
            Button(action: { showingAlert = true }, label: {
                Text("Logout")
            })
        } label: {
            Button(action: {  }) {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle").imageScale(.large)
            }
        }.alert(isPresented:$showingAlert){
            Alert(title: Text("Logout?"),
                  message: Text("Are you sure you want to logout?"),
                  primaryButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: { }),
                  secondaryButton: .cancel())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually my issue was calling multiple alert.

Comment: that is not the question you asked, `How can I show an alert on a button click of a menu`

Answer (score 0):

Create one function for logout action

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Menu{
              Button("Profile", action: {})
              Button("Settings", action: {})
              Button("Logout", action: logoutAction)
    }
}

func logoutAction() {
}}
```

Add your alert related call inside logoutAction method